# Creating a frustum for culling in world-space glm matrices

Tags: opengl, mathematics, culling, frustum

I need to do frustum culling where the bounding boxes are in world-space to determine which entities get to be updated/drawn. I was trying to use the classic projection/view matrix plane extraction method but it doesn't seem to work with perspective matrices created by GLM. Is this method appropriate for world-space culling? It seems like it would be (takes the eye position into account and the projection matrix shapes the frustum).

I've only looked at the near/far planes extract so far and they're wrong for a frustum sitting at the origin (Both have a c component that's negative which means near and far are facing the same direction). Also, since the d components can't match the near/far clipping values with this method is it wrong for world-space culling?

Comment: Are you using the plane extraction algorithm for OpenGL-style right-handed column-major projection matrices.  They are not the same as typical D3D matrices.  Make sure you know which handed-ness your algorithm uses (GL/glm is right-handed by convention), and to remember that glm matrices are column-major.  I know I can easily extract frustrum planes from a GL projection matrix identical to what glm makes, so it definitely works and is doable.

Comment: Yes I'm extracting for column-major. It was originally written as row-major but when I switched to GLM I updated it. It did actually pass my tests when it was written for row-major. I'm not sure that GLM produces a projection matrix identical to OpenGL's - in the header it appeared to be row-major.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem - GLM's interface for accessing the matrix is backwards compared to the matrix used by the original frustum extraction paper for OpenGL.